# Getting X Display on Ubuntu 18.04 (works on 14.04)

Tags: command-line, systemd, 18.04, systemd-logind

On Ubuntu 14.04, I run following command to get DISPLAY server value for user johndoe

```
loginctl show-session $(loginctl -a show-user johndoe | grep Display | sed 's/Display.//g') | grep Display
```

and get following output

`Display=:0`

This does not work on Ubuntu 18.04 and I get nothing in return. This is because `loginctl show-session $(.....)` part of command has no `Display` property. Following is that output

```
Id=1
User=1000
Name=johndoe
Timestamp=Sun 2018-01-28 08:23:56 PST
TimestampMonotonic=10357101
VTNr=1
Seat=seat0
TTY=tty1
Remote=no
Service=gdm-autologin
Scope=session-1.scope
Leader=937
Audit=1
Type=x11
Class=user
Active=yes
State=active
IdleHint=no
IdleSinceHint=0
IdleSinceHintMonotonic=0
LockedHint=no
```

How can I get DISPLAY value then?

**UPDATE 001**

Here is output of `env`, it shows display. But I want to get it by username like in the question at top, and that doesn't work.

```
CLUTTER_IM_MODULE=xim
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
XDG_MENU_PREFIX=gnome-
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
DISPLAY=:0
GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=ubuntu
COLORTERM=truecolor
DESKTOP_AUTOSTART_ID=103724b41fe83ecb6c152542594670522500000011280007
USERNAME=johndoe
XDG_VTNR=2
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
XDG_SESSION_ID=5
USER=johndoe
DESKTOP_SESSION=ubuntu
QT4_IM_MODULE=xim
TEXTDOMAINDIR=/usr/share/locale/
GNOME_TERMINAL_SCREEN=/org/gnome/Terminal/screen/34510819_0c4e_4d16_b23f_d3178cc68fd9
PWD=/home/johndoe
HOME=/home/johndoe
TEXTDOMAIN=im-config
SSH_AGENT_PID=1223
QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11
XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=ubuntu
GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge
WINDOWPATH=2
TERM=xterm-256color
SHELL=/bin/bash
VTE_VERSION=5201
QT_IM_MODULE=xim
XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
IM_CONFIG_PHASE=2
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=ubuntu:GNOME
GPG_AGENT_INFO=/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1
GNOME_TERMINAL_SERVICE=:1.77
XDG_SEAT=seat0
SHLVL=1
GDMSESSION=ubuntu
GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID=this-is-deprecated
LOGNAME=johndoe
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
XAUTHORITY=/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority
XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
SESSION_MANAGER=local/johndoe-johndoeBox:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1128,unix/johndoe-johndoeBox:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1128
LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus
_=/usr/bin/env
```

Comment: Your approach works fine on a Lubuntu 16.04 as well as on a Kubuntu 18.04 machine for me. I wanted to throw in `loginctl`'s `-p` option, but that doesn't solve your problem – something is fishy here…

Answer (score 1):

`johndoe` has a Wayland session, which doesn't use the DISPLAY variable. If you really need to still use X11, have John Doe log into an X11 session instead and try again.

@dessert gets a different result because they are using an X11 session on 18.04.

Comment: It makes sense generally but why is there `Type=x11` in the listing?

Comment: @Melebius My guess may be wrong. According to this page, `Type=x11` *should* correctly indicate an X11 session is active: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/202891/how-to-know-whether-wayland-or-x11-is-being-used#325972 Maybe there is a difference between native X11 and XWayland (X11 within Wayland?)

Comment: I need X Display so that my cron job targets correct display. How can I do that if it is a Wayland session?

Comment: Do you need a Wayland session? 18.04 continues to support X.

Comment: If Wayland is default with Ubuntu 18.04, then I'd prefer it and avoid any manual effort to switch to X11.

Comment: Is this for your own desktop? You only have to apply manual effort once, when you login, to select a different session from the drop down menu. After that the preference is remembered.

Comment: No, actually this is for our clients who will run our Ubuntu app and they sure will not be technical enough. If switching can be done by any shell command, then it'll be great and we'll do it via some script.

Comment: plz check update 001 in question